# JMS fault tolerant asynchronous publisher

Tags: java, jms, messaging

In our architecture JMS publisher may continue to work (and generate new messages) even if connection with local network is lost. Is it possible to make publisher server tolerant to network or broker outages with JMS:

1. publish call may not block application, even if broker is not available;
2. published messages (during outage) must be delivered after network connection is restored;

As far as I understand it can be done with embedded (local) broker on each publishing machine. If it's the only way, are there any non obvious problems with that topology - performance, maintenance, etc? Will the local broker be tolerant to outages by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tried this but it seems like you could use local failover to reduce impedance:
With ActiveMQ you can configure a failover transport:

```
failover:(tcp://primary:61616,tcp://secondary:61616)?randomize=false
```

To try and draw this:

```
client +---> primary: network broker <-------+
       |                                     |
       +---> secondary: embedded broker -----+
```

Here primary would be your network broker, and your secondary broker would be the locally embedded broker with a bridge to the primary broker.  This seems like it would work well when the client publishes allot; I'm not sure if this would be any better for subscribes then the solution put forward by @Biju: illustrated below:

```
client +---> secondary: embedded broker ------> primary: network broker
```

For example here is my embedded broker (which is usually non-persistent).

```
<bean id="activeMQBroker" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService">
    <property name="transportConnectors">
        <list>
                <bean id="brokerConnection" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector">
                    <property name="connectUri">
                        <bean id="brokerURI" class="java.net.URI">
                            <constructor-arg value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="persistent" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I make second broker itself tolerant to connection loss? What type of connection between brokers should be to prevent second one from dying, hanging and gurantee messages delivery after network connection restored?

Comment: The embedded broker typically has a file store where it writes incoming messages to.  The bridge should tolerate connection loss (from what I remember).  See http://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge.html.

Comment: Embedded broker with failover transport works so far. Though, there is a bug in Active MQ which prevents using embedded broker in subscriber processes as well: [AMQ-3213](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3213). Sometimes, the same problem occurs even with one embedded broker (publisher) and one remote. Solution seems to be right and AMQ seems to be buggy.

Comment: I remember ActiveMQ in failover mode occasionally seemed buggy to me (mostly corner cases that didn't seem to work as I would have expected) when I was using it, but I was never sure if it was my setup or something I just didn't grasp about JMS.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can think of is along the lines you have suggested -

1. Have a local embedded broker and provide a bridge from this embedded broker to a network based broker. Even the local one can go down though, so you may have to publish transactionally between your resources(db and jms infrastructure)
2. Do not publish directly, instead have an abstraction which buffers it - to a database, file, or like above to a local embedded jms, and provide a bridge like above from the buffer to the JMS queue.

Comment: I think, if embedded broker goes down it can be considered like fatal publisher error, like if database layer goes down

Comment: "abstraction which buffers ..." - exactly! But I want that functionality out of the box. Why do I need JMS if I have to write additional buffering and persistent layers to it?

Comment: @Shcheklein, true, you don't have to write any buffering layer, if the source of messages(db say) and destination(jms queue) can be pulled into a common transaction(XA)

Answer (score 0):

A distributed architecture if queue managers \ brokers is very common in cases as you describe.

The exact configuration depends on the specific product you use, but it's usually well documented and easy to manage

regarding local redundancy, you may use two such queue manager in a fault tolerant configuration (again - the exact method of creating fault tolerant clusters is product dependent) - but this appears to be some what of an overkill.

JMS standardizes only the API of the message queue provider, other

Comment: That's the most frustrating aspect of the JMS 'spec' (security is not defined either).  You can write perfectly portable JMS code, but its not deploy-able out of the box.